# Error ternary operator not working in flutter

Tags: flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'answers': ['black', 'Red', 'Green', 'white']
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
      'answers': ['Lion', 'Tiger', 'rabbit', 'horse']
    },
    {
      'questionText': "What\'s your favourite movie",
      'answers': ['bahubali', 'frozen', 'piratesofcarbien', 'harrypotter']
    },
  ];
  bool t = true;
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = (_questionIndex + 1);
      print("The value of t is =========${t}");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']);
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body:  _questionIndex < questions.length ? Column(
                children: [
                  Question(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']),
                  ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
                      .map((answer) {
                    return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
                  }).toList()
                ],
              )
            : Center(child: Text("You did it! "),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my flutter code I am in a situation when my **_questionIndex** variable less than the length of list **questions** I have to return one widget else I have to return another Widget. I had written code according to that.
But here my problem is even though The condition in **ternary operator** is false it is not executing the negative one that is `Center(child: Text("You did it! "),)`

Answer (score 2):

Your ternary code is actually completely correct. However, once the _questionIndex variable is equal to the number of elements in the questions list, It throws an error because it cannot fetch the question at index _questionIndex. Since it hits the error, it never gets to rebuild the widget tree with the else from the ternary operation.

I think you actually only need to remove this one line:

```
print(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']);
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much @Alex Collete, It resolved my errror.

Comment: @chalapathinagavarmabhupathira, glad I could help!